# Laravel 5.6: Pagination for a POST route gives blank pages on all links except first

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a search form that works well with a post method, however the problem is that the pagination links don't work. Except the first page, all other pages give blank pages. I have read somewhere that pagination doesn't work well with `POST` method. 
However, when I change my form and route to "get" method then I get blank page even on the first page. Nothing gets displayed.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('reports/search','ReportsController@search');
```

This is my form

```
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal" action="{{action('ReportsController@search')}}">
    <!--  {{csrf_field()}} used only with POST-->
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my Controller code

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $showData = sys_data::paginate(10);
    return view('reports-data-view', compact('showData'));
}
```

The issue is when I change form and route method to `POST` then it works but then the pagination links show blank pages.

And when I change the method to `GET` then it doesn't work. Shows blank page  as soon as I hit submit button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

Actually since the GET link was /reports/search, the request was going to "show($id)" function of the controller by default since it was taking "research" in the link as an argument.

All I did was, change the route to '/reports/search/view', and it started working and went to the correct custom function "search()" in my ReportsController.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your form

```
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('reports/search')}}">
```

Comment: Hi, it still gives blank page with your suggestion.  Any other suggestion?